# A sequel to the Pied Piper of Hamelin

Tags: story-identification, fairy-tales

I remember a children's fantasy book published by or before about 1960 which was sort of a sequel to the Pied Piper of Hamelin.

I am not sure if I read the book or only read the description of it on the dust jacket.

Anyway, the book is supposed to be after the Pied Piper takes the children from Hamelin, and the children tell each other stories to pass the time.  And it is possible that the writer merely retold various fairy tales he was familiar with, supposing that they would be known to the children of Hamelin, instead of making up his own stories.

I don't remember whether the book had an overall plot or was really just an anthology of fairy tales with the Pied Piper story as a frame story.

Can anyone tell me more about this book?

Comment: Joseph Cotter wrote a book of poems in 1939 called 'Sequel to the Pied Piper of Hamelin and Other Stories'.